# using now() as default value in tztsrange in postgresql 9.2

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Is it possible to define `now()` as a start value for `tztsrange` data type introduced in postgresql 9.2? I tried to use this

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ALTER COLUMN tstz_range SET DEFAULT '[now,infinity]'::tstzrange;
```

But in such expression `now()` is evaluated into current time stamp by altering table and default value is despite always the same:

```
'["2012-09-18 15:00:47.334196+02",infinity]'::tstzrange;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated [in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/rangetypes.html) you can define a range with the according function:

```
SELECT tstzrange(now(), 'infinity', '[)');
┌────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                 tstzrange                  │
├────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ ["2012-09-18 15:33:50.186351+00",infinity) │
└────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

So you can easily create a default value using the function:

```
CREATE TABLE plop (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY, 
  some_range tstzrange DEFAULT tstzrange(now(), 'infinity', '[)')
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to define my own function wich returns tstzrange, but this solution is much more elegant.